# Items (scripts) in custom toolbar are not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, toolbar

I created custom toolbar in my working mxd and added few menus to it:

[image]

Using customize dialog I added some system and my own tools (scripts) to it:

[image]

It worked great for last two months or so, providing very fast access to most frequently used tools. However yesterday after long 4 days weekend I found that the only items in menu still working are the ones pointing to system tools. Nothing happens when I click on the item pointing to my own tools.

**I did not:**

1. remove tools from COMMANDS using CUSTOMIZE dialog. Moreover if I click description within that dialog, it gives me correct tool description
2. physically moved scripts.

What went wrong? How to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Just to rule out one obvious cause ... do the tools work if you browse to them?

Comment: Yes they do. Drives me nuts

Comment: Is there any chance that your Normal.mxt has been re-initiated?

Comment: No changes to Normal.mxt. I would of lost my customization, wouldn't I? The only thing changed is Z value in Environment settings (from Disable to Enable). Please don't tell me that this broke all the links to scripts.

Comment: Maybe a bug. Did you try to remove the tools and then re-add them to the commands list and then add them to the menu?

Comment: Yes I had to redo everything using very long procedure: remove item from menu, remove tool from commands, close customize dialog, open it again, browse to toolbox of interest and add it to 'geoprocessing tools' and finally drag and drop it to menu. They work after this. Shorter workaround is not working. So something bad happened to 'geoprocessing' list and this is a concern.

Comment: Are your custom scripts .net or python?  Also, what version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Python. 10.2.1. My latest suspicion is changing path in parent mxd from relative to full or other way around. MXD path is d:\ESRI\Tools\_wbench.mxd. Scripts are sitting in c:\ESRI\Tools\My Toolboxes. It seems relative/full still have to work both

Comment: Has your IT security changed anything recently?  Try running your application as Administrator.

Comment: I already fixed it, by simply repeating all the steps. I just want to avoid this happening again

Comment: Did a server change? We have had servers replaced with a name that is 1 character different oit-servername1 vs oit-servernamef. Path \\file\mydata does not change.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).